# Failing to replicate CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hash) in powershell

Tags: javascript, powershell, cryptography, hmac

I'm trying to replicate this code in powershell:

```
const hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hash), salt);
seed = hmac.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
```

what I think it does - parse the `hash` variable into a binary representation and then uses that to create a new hash with HmacSHA256. My powershell code:

```
    $hmacsha = $hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
    $hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($salt)
    $signatureRaw = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($hash))
    $signature = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($signatureRaw).Replace('-','').ToLower()
```

as far as my understanding goes `[Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($hash)` should achieve that exactly, but the results do not match. code uses same values for hash and salt across languages. JS results:

```
original hash: 1c46b79912c6109fe8ccf2dde7e8f931e7a95471e38e22865cd1df719a48d405
resulting hash: 4a9732c4a1f4bd2da1e59f3714c943ef662e664e11ea8364bee870916c42ac5c
```

Powershell results:

```
original hash: 1c46b79912c6109fe8ccf2dde7e8f931e7a95471e38e22865cd1df719a48d405
resulting hash: 58693c49074149321ec8f440e36f88a3369203c91df8a9c308f78f09ac66733f
```

Comment: In the Powershell code, the hash must not be UTF8 encoded, but hex decoded, e.g. with `$hash = [byte[] -split ($hash -replace '..', '0x$& ')`, from [here, at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54543794/9014097).

Comment: I'm getting another result, but it still doesn't match the javascript one -..-

Comment: On my machine, both codes provide identical results after adaptation. However, I use my own example, because the key `salt`/`$salt` was not posted. Can you post the key? Or if not, a _test_ key and the results for each code?

Comment: nah, this is not a secret: `$salt = '0000000000000000004d6ec16dafe9d8370958664c1dc422f452892264c59526'`. Can you provide your code in an answer? maybe I'm using it in a wrong fashion?

Comment: Also with your key both results are identical on my machine. I will post my code in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Powershell code the hash must not be UTF8 encoded, but hex decoded, e.g. with

```
$hash = [byte[]] -split ($hash -replace '..', '0x$& ')
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54543794/9014097).

Using the following code:

```
$hmacsha = $hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$salt = "0000000000000000004d6ec16dafe9d8370958664c1dc422f452892264c59526"
$hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($salt)
$hash = "1c46b79912c6109fe8ccf2dde7e8f931e7a95471e38e22865cd1df719a48d405"
$hash = [byte[]] -split ($hash -replace '..', '0x$& ')
$signatureRaw = $hmacsha.ComputeHash($hash)
$signature = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($signatureRaw).Replace('-','').ToLower()
Write-Output $signature
```

the result is identical to that of the JavaScript code:

```
4a9732c4a1f4bd2da1e59f3714c943ef662e664e11ea8364bee870916c42ac5c
```