# How can I enable the "Privacy control > Desktop capture" setting in Nvidia GeForce Experience with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, nvidia

I want to enable the "Privacy control > Desktop capture" setting programmatically so I can take screenshots after installing Nvidia Geforce Experience through Chocolatey without having to go through the UI.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After diffing the registry before/after toggling the setting, they are stored in the registry as below:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\Global\ShadowPlay\NVSPCAPS]
"DwmEnabled"=hex:01,00,00,00
"DwmEnabledUser"=hex:01,00,00,00
```

Do your choco install:

```
choco install geforce-game-ready-driver
```

and launch GeForce Experience. Sometimes GFE will do an update of some sort on-first-launch. If this is done after the PowerShell below it may blow away our changes.

Reboot to be safe and run the below in a PowerShell admin console which applies the registry settings and restarts the managing service (NvContainerLocalSystem):

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\Global\ShadowPlay\NVSPCAPS' -Name DwmEnabledUser -Type Binary -Value ([byte[]](0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00))
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\Global\ShadowPlay\NVSPCAPS' -Name DwmEnabled -Type Binary -Value ([byte[]](0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00))
Write-Host "Restarting service: NvContainerLocalSystem... " -NoNewline
Restart-Service -Name NvContainerLocalSystem
Write-Host "Done"
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6551342/4612820